# Check ISNULL for boolean value in LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I convert this SQL statement in LINQ query?

```
ISNULL(IsBlocked,0) = 0
```

`IsBlocked` is a column in the table `Persons`.

Comment: `(IsBlocked ?? 0) == 0` or `(IsBlocked == 0 || IsBlocked is null)`

Comment: `IsBlocked.HasValue ? IsBlocked.Value : false` here `IsBlocked` data type is `bool?`

Comment: yes isblocked is bool, I need to check whether it is null or zero

Comment: Can you provide the minimal schema of your persons table because I want to know the datatype of your IsBlocked column.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have 2 solutions for you. One is for INT or SMALLINT DataType and another is for BIT DataType in Database.
If your IsBlocked Column is BIT TYPE in SQL Server then you can the code given below.

```
 //This Class Represent as your Table Schema
public class PersonTableOne
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? IsBlocked { get; set; }
}

void TestMethod1()
{
        List<PersonTableOne> personItems = new List<PersonTableOne>();
        personItems.Add(new PersonTableOne() { PersonID = 1, Name= "A" ,IsBlocked=null});
        personItems.Add(new PersonTableOne() { PersonID = 2, Name = "B", IsBlocked = true });
        personItems.Add(new PersonTableOne() { PersonID = 2, Name = "C", IsBlocked = false });

        var answare = from m in personItems
                      where (m.IsBlocked ?? false) == false
                      select m;
}
```

**Note:** Class is the representation of table and List is your table rows.

If you IsBlocked Column is INT/SMALLINT TYPE in SQL Server then you can the code given below.

```
 public class PersonTableTwo
 {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? IsBlocked { get; set; }
 }
 void TestMethod2()
 {
        List<PersonTableTwo> personItems = new List<PersonTableTwo>();
        personItems.Add(new PersonTableTwo() { PersonID = 1, Name = "A", IsBlocked = null });
        personItems.Add(new PersonTableTwo() { PersonID = 2, Name = "B", IsBlocked = 1 });
        personItems.Add(new PersonTableTwo() { PersonID = 2, Name = "C", IsBlocked = 0 });

        var answare = from m in personItems
                      where (m.IsBlocked ?? 0) == 0
                      select m;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var result = from a.IsBlocked in db.Persons where a.IsBlocked == null 
select new { IsBlocked = false};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert field to string and check if is null or empty.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(IsBlocked.ToString()) //this is going to be true if IsBlocked = null
```